# Html 5 x 5 matrix like controlin textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to create a simple html table in grid having values like 1 to 25  and ordered in a matrix / grid fashion.
I want that grid to show up in a a fashion like jquery ui datetime control.

```
@for(int i =0;i<5;i++){ for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
<input type="button" id="foo">
if(j==4){
<br/>

}

}
```

Then using above code as editor template and attach it to a textbox.

Any help pointers are much appreciated.

Regards

Bilal

}

Comment: The question is how to show n hide in a way like we get the calendar control in a customised madal type dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: ? (hand written - untested)

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [UIHint("MyCustomEditorTemplateType")]
    public int MyField { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyField)
```

Editor Template:

```
@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = "forpopupcontrol" })
<div id="@(string.Format("{0}_container", Html.IdFor(m => m)))" style="display:none">
    @* code build table here *@
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('.forpopupcontrol').focus(function()
        {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_Container').show();
        }).blur(function()
        {                
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_Container').hide();
        });
    }        
</script>
```